# How to test web-ext in my current browser

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-ext

I am using web-ext to create and test my extension. When I run `web-ext run` it will launch a debug Firefox with a new profile. How can I use web-ext to develop my extension using my current browser.

One major reason I want to use one browser is to maintain login sessions. I'm making an extension for a website with 2FA and their security is going haywire (as it should). Instead, I have saved the pages as Complete HTML and I'm developing using cached versions of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run your extension in the current browser.
You can however run your extension with your existing profile using "--firefox-profile", but it will still run a new instance of the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I did try the profile option, but since it copies the profile it takes quite a while to launch each time. I mostly want it so I don't have 2 browsers open when developing, both need to be logged in.